# tea4Cups prehook sketch not running certain libraries

Tags: python, raspbian, cups

I am using tea4cups backend with the CUPS printing system.

I'm writing a prehook in which I run a python script which turns on the printer via GPIO/relays and sets a cron task to turn it off after set time.

I have narrowed down my problem to the point that I have identified I cannot use certain python libraries. Namely, `crontab` and `logging`.

Whenever I import these libraries in the python script, the tea4cups prehook can't exit successfully. The job status shows this:

```
completed at
Mon 02 Apr 2018 12:59:44 UTC 
"Tea4CUPS v3.12_official (PID 22795) : Prehook prehook_new on printer Brother_HL_5470DW_Tea4Cups didn't exit successfully."
```

Keep in mind my script runs flawlessly when I run it manually from the terminal. It's just that the tea4cups can't run it when I import these libraries into the script.

Here is the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_DHT
from sys import argv, exit
import crontab
import logging

# Initialize temperature sensor
sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22

# Pin definitions
DHTPin = 17
printPin = 27
heatPin = 22

# Pin Setup
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(heatPin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(printPin, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(heatPin, GPIO.HIGH)

# Initialize variables
temperature = 0

# Main Program
print("final")
```

Here is the tea4cups.conf file ending where I mention this prehook:

```
prehook_new : python /home/pi/printserver/debug
```

Here is the permissions for the python script:

[image]

Can someone help me how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use the full path to the python programme. Use `which python` to get it.

Second, I suspect, that the print line confuses tea4CUPS (but I didn't read all of tea4CUPS' code. If you look at its source code, you can see that a `stdioRedirSystem` method is called to call your programme.

Third, I recommend you to enable debug mode in tea4cups' config file (`/etc/cups/tea4cups.conf`) and then look into the cups error file (`/var/log/cups/error.log`).